# In App pagination set up in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, pagination

I had set up pagination through coding from app side so I just get all data from api only once and than set up pagination as bellow method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView == self.tblForList)
    {
        if (indexPath.row == arrForList.count - 1 && arrForList.count < arrForMainList.count)
        {
            offset += limit;
            page++;
            [self getMore25DataFromMainAry];
        }
    }
}
```

here issue is if user scroll more than one time so quickly and yet UITableView is not reloaded successfully method being called more than one time hence my offset is increased to beyond MainArray Count and my app get crashed.

So please share your suggestion to avoid crashing.Here I applied 25 limit for pagination so every time after 25 item added to arraylist getMore25Data should be called till offset is less than arrrMainList.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should add a `BOOL` property to make `getMore25DataFromMainAry` can't be called while it's running.

```
@interface YourClass ()

@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL loading;

@end

@implementation YourClass

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if(tableView == self.tblForList) {
    if (indexPath.row == arrForList.count - 1 && arrForList.count < arrForMainList.count) {
      [self getMore25DataFromMainAry];
    }
  }
}

- (void)getMore25DataFromMainAry {
  if (self.loading) {
    // Don't do anything until loading more completely
    return;
  }

  // Start loading more
  self.loading = YES;

  offset += limit;
  page++;

  // Do whatever you want to load more data.

  // After receiving new data, set |self.loading| to NO
  self.loading = NO;
}

@end
```